# What should be the arguments/declaration for ofstream in int main in C++?

Tags: c++, ofstream

When I tested `ofstream` under `int main()` whose the sole purpose is to output data into a file, then I can compile with no problem.  However, when I have other arguments inside `int main(...)`, the following errors come up. How do I declare `ofstream` in `int main(...)`?

```
error: ‘ofstream’ was not declared in this scope
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘phi_file’
error: ‘phi_file’ was not declared in this scope

int main(int argc, char** args, double phi_fcn())
{ 

  int frame ; 

  double *x, *y, *vx, *vy ;

  x = new double[N_POINTS] ; y = new double[N_POINTS] ; 
  vx = new double[N_POINTS] ; vy = new double[N_POINTS] ; 

  char file_name[255] ;

  printf("The number of particles is N_POINTS=%d;\n",N_POINTS) ;
  printf("the box size is L=%4.2f; ",L) ;
  printf("the interaction radius is a=%17.16f;\n",a) ;
  printf("the radius of repulsion is R_R=%17.16f;\n",R_R) ;
  printf("the radius of repulsion squared is R_R_SQUARED=%17.16f;\n",R_R_SQUARED) ;
  printf("the radius of orientation is R_O=%17.16f;\n",R_O) ;
  printf("the radius of orientation squared is R_O_SQUARED=%17.16f;\n",R_O_SQUARED) ;

  // generate initial distribution of particles

  icond_uniform(x,y,vx,vy,N_POINTS) ;

  // draw the first picture

  sprintf( file_name, "tga_files/out%04d.tga", 0 );

  drawPicture(file_name,RES_X,RES_Y,x,y,N_POINTS);

ofstream phi_file;//create a phi_file to write to
phi_file.open("phi_per_timestep.dat");***

  // time stepping loop

  for (frame=1; frame<N_FRAMES; frame++) 
    {

      interact_all(x,y,vx,vy,N_POINTS);

      advect(x,y,vx,vy,N_POINTS);

      // output data into graphics file

      sprintf( file_name, "tga_files/out%04d.tga", frame );

      drawPicture(file_name,RES_X,RES_Y,x,y,N_POINTS);

      phi_file << phi_fcn();

    }
phi_file.close();
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why does your `main` function have other arguments?  What headers are you including?  Do you have any using directives?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "tga.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>

Comment: all the above are included.   If I don't have the double phi_fcn() inside int main(), then there's another error coming up saying phi_fcn() is not declared. Once I added it, that error goes away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `#include <fstream>` and qualify `ofstream` as `std::ofstream`.

Also note that your signature for main is not allowed by the standard and may or may not cause random unpredictable problems for you.

Answer (score 7):

In C++, `main` must have one of the following two signatures:

```
int main();
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
```

It is illegal to write a `main` function that takes any parameters other than these, since these are typically set up either by the operating system or by the C++ language runtime.  This may be the cause of your error.

Alternatively, the fact that you're getting these errors could indicate that you've forgotten to `#include` the appropriate header files.  Did you `#include <fstream>` at the top of your program?

Comment: It would be legal, if the implementation had an extension for main taking a function as the third argument. But I guess the missing include is more likely. :-)

Comment: I did have #include at the top of the program. If I don't have the double phi_fcn() inside int main(), then there's another error coming up saying phi_fcn() is not declared.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting an error saying that phi_fcn() is not declared, then there is another #include you need to be adding that has that function defined in it, probably. Adding it as a parameter to main() is not a solution.